# Get product attribute 'option label'?

Tags: product, attributes

I have manage to retrieve the value for an attribute relative to a particular product

```
 $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
 $attribute_code = 'code';
 $value =  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
        ->getAttributeRawValue($prod_id, $attribute_code, $store_id);
```

What I miss here is the label associated to the attribute value.

How can I get it, without load the full product object ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code works fine and avoid to load the entire product obj

```
$option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
    ->getAttributeRawValue($prod_id, $attribure_code, $store_id);
```

**Method 1**

```
$option_value = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setStoreFilter($store_id)
    ->setIdFilter($option_id)
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getValue();
```

**Method 2** ([@Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/how-can-i-get-attribute-option-label-having-attribute-value))

```
// to be tested
// not loading the product - just creating a simple instance
$singleton_prod = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')
     ->setStoreId($store_id)
     ->setData($attribure_code, $option_id); 
$optionLabel = $singleton_prod->getAttributeText($attribure_code);
```

Comment: Regarding Method2 , it should be $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->setYourAttributeCode($yourAttributeOptionId); $productOptionLabel = $_product->getAttributeText($yourAtrributeCode); Credits to @Marius - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8396/695

Comment: I don't see the difference in the code you posted. setYourAttributeCode($value) or setData($attribute_code, value) is the same ( credit to varien team :)

Comment: setData doesn't work , whereas setAttributeCode works , atleast in my case ...(verified with older 1.6.1.x version and in the recent 1.9.3.x. version), though the difference is not visible.

Comment: this sound very strange to me, I test it when I have some time and updated the answer if required, thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can also use some thing like this if you have `$product` variable.

```
$product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);
```

Comment: The only problem here is the OP already has the resource model.

Comment: Yes, i just suggest other method to retrieve label, if op has product_id then may be he has product object

Comment: I don't want to load the full prod model only for getting the label if possible ...

Comment: getAttributeRawValue only gives you value of particular attribute

Answer (score 4):

I used this code.

```
$some_attr_code = "brand"
$optionId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('option_id');

/** @var Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute $attribute */
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $some_attr_code);
$label = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
if($optionId){
  $optionLabel = $attribute->getFrontend()->getOption($optionId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution isn't bound to a strict model or a resource model and can be used to retrieve an option label of an attribute that is assigned to whatever entity type:

```
// In your case $entityType should be `catalog_product`
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode);
echo $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
```

FYI, `$attribute->getSource()` returns an instance of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table` which has the following methods:

```
Array
(
    [0] => getAllOptions
    [1] => getOptionText
    [2] => addValueSortToCollection
    [3] => getFlatColums
    [4] => getFlatIndexes
    [5] => getFlatUpdateSelect
    [6] => setAttribute
    [7] => getAttribute
    [8] => getOptionId
    [9] => getIndexOptionText
)
```

I should note that *Method 1* from accepted answer throws an SQL error in Magento v1.9.4 (I'm not sure about the other versions):

```
Column 'option_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

The reason could be found in the below generated SQL query:

```
SELECT
    `main_table`.*,
    `tdv`.`value` AS `default_value`,
    `tsv`.`value` AS `store_default_value`,
IF
    ( tsv.value_id > 0, tsv.VALUE, tdv.VALUE ) AS `value` 
FROM
    `eav_attribute_option` AS `main_table`
    INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `tdv` ON tdv.option_id = main_table.option_id
    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `tsv` ON tsv.option_id = main_table.option_id 
    AND tsv.store_id = 0 
WHERE
    ( tdv.store_id = 0 ) 
    # This is the culprit
    AND ( `option_id` IN ( 9999 ) )
```

Comment: This is an excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attribute_code);
$label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I'm asking ... the value of the attribute is related to a particular product/store id ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but it really wasn't clear from your question...

Comment: Anyway, in attribute model `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute` you also have the method `getStoreLabel($storeId = null)`

Comment: ... "for an attribute relative to a particular product" :)