# how to display a label and value of the attribute in the list of products if there is an attribute value?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-list

I have a question about the attributes and labels. I need to label and value appear in the list of products , only those that relate to the product . I did the following in `list.phtml`. I entered the code:

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('obiem_baka')->getStoreLabel(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('obiem_baka');?>
```

The problem is that the label is displayed is always displayed , even if no value . I need that to label displayed only when there is a value .

Thank you so much.

P.S. I apologize for the error , does not speak English .

Comment: Hope this help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3003/get-product-attribute-option-label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $attributeText = $_product->getAttributeText('obiem_baka');?>
<?php if($attributeText):?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('obiem_baka')->getStoreLabel(); ?>
<?php echo $attributeText;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('obiem_baka')):?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('obiem_baka')->getStoreLabel(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('obiem_baka');?>
<?php endif;?>
```